# Why was the answer to "Find out how many people are downloading/using a specific version of a npm package?" deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54656306/) ([screenshot for <10k users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qC6Hf.png)) I posted to [Find out how many people are downloading/using a specific version of a npm package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54655221/find-out-how-many-people-are-downloading-using-a-specific-version-of-a-npm-packa) directly answers the question.

Why was the answer deleted?

Comment: This seems like an awful lot of effort for a question that is off-topic.

Comment: @fbueckert Yes. Have been in that situation several times, from Web Speech API to other web platform features. Ultimately had to write the specification and code for self, including performing testing. That is what have been trying to convey. Evidently lost on the users who want the feature.

Comment: I don't think telling someone to do all the work for a feature counts as an answer; it still doesn't actually solve the problem.  It also doesn't help to actually answer off-topic questions.  My point was that it seems this Meta question is more about tilting at windmills; you're expending an awful lot of effort on what is ultimately not a good question.

Comment: @fbueckert The problem can only be solved by writing the specification, performing tests. Apparently people believe that all they need to do is ask for something and others will do all the work. Or, have yet to actually test a feature request, or believe that a clear specification and testing is not required; only the request is needed.  Yes, the effort apparently is not considered helpful. The users will just have to find out themselves. Perhaps they will get lucky and someone will do all of the work for them and implement the feature as soon as they read the request. In any event, tried.

Comment: Please read this if you can't ask new questions: **[What can I do when getting “We are no longer accepting questions from this account”?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255583)**

Answer (score 27):

I'm not entirely sure why you've decided to bring this up in a public forum and assert that my decision makes "no sense", but now that you have, let me see if I can explain the good sense that was involved.

I came upon the post in question due to 5 different flags having been raised by community members, both on comments and on the post itself. [BugHunterUK has already admitted to having cast one of the flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/380115). His "not an answer" flag was completely valid. Your "write the specifications and then do the work yourself" post was emphatically *not* an answer to the question, so I deleted it.

BugHunterUK's comment left under the answer in question pretty well sums up my thinking:

> @guest271314 this answer does not in any way attempt to answer the OP and neither is the answer relevant to this question.

Even if you can argue that this is an "answer" (as [you tried to do here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/380114/why-was-the-answer-to-find-out-how-many-people-are-downloading-using-a-specific/380115#comment669692_380115)), in the sense that it's how one should correctly tackle a programming problem, then it would literally be an answer to *every question on this site*. Since that renders the concept of Q&A meaningless, we're going to just say it's not an answer.

We'll leave aside the issue of whether you should have known that this does not meet [our standards for an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering), since having an answer deleted is not a punitive action—just cleaning the place up.

Deleting the answer also took care of the abusive comments that were left underneath it, saving me the trouble of having to read them and do an extensive clean-up.

Now, when I handle "not an answer" flags, I will commonly take a look at the question, too, just to see if that might be playing some role in attracting poor-quality answers. In this case, it seemed clear to me (and to two other users) that the question was not suitable for Stack Overflow. It wasn't the question's fault this time for attracting a non-answer, but it just wasn't asking a question that we are equipped to answer. Furthermore, by the time I looked at it, it seemed that janpio had already found his answer and [edited it into the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/54655221/2).

There's a possibility that the question could be edited into shape, and thus become a candidate for re-opening. Unfortunately, I'm not a domain expert, didn't feel qualified to edit the question myself, and didn't really have the time to do so properly. That's why I closed it, rather than deleting it.

Unfortunately, I wasn't done with the page yet, because there was an ocean of flags on comments to the question, as well. By this time, I was growing somewhat tired of this, and beginning to recall handling an ocean of flags on at least two different comment exchanges that you were involved in yesterday. I read through the comments here and pruned them very judiciously. Yes, that meant deleting a large number of your comments, as it did in the last several comment exchanges you were involved in that I handled flags on.

I then requested privately that you try and keep the noise to a minimum. As I'm sure you know, you tend to have a somewhat abrasive style of communication. I don't personally have an issue with that, since I have somewhat of the same style. You've also done a reasonable job of not personally attacking anyone lately, which means you haven't directly violated our community's code of conduct. However, you do tend to feel that you have to be right, which means you keep arguing and arguing and arguing long after it's obvious that there is no good that can possibly come of continuing the discussion. I pointed out—and want to emphasize again—that sometimes it's okay to just disagree with people and walk away from a discussion amicably. Please consider exercising that option more frequently.

Comment: Edited the question to remove the "makes no sense" part. Disagree with _"Your "write the specifications and then do the work yourself" post was emphatically not an answer to the question"_ and reiterate that here, as have made more than one "feature request" at specifications/standards/browsers and at some point realized that if did not do the work for self the work would not get done  by simply asking someone else to do the work (that is, experience re "feature request"s). Was trying to help. At the same time will act on the suggestion at private message and closing sentences of your answer.

Comment: @guest271314 you do know your proposal to extend a closed source system is illogical right? Not to mention [this issue has been open since 2014](https://github.com/npm/download-counts/issues/6) on NPM and the only people who can change the code is the NPM staff. As you can see by the staffs responses they don't have the resources to implement. And that's the end of the line. Your answer might be perfectly valid in a different context, for a different question, but in this case it wasn't. I've had many answers removed in my time here. Don't sweat it. Learn and move on.

Comment: @BugHunterUK _"As you can see by the staffs responses they don't have the resources to implement."_ That lends to the posted answer being helpful. The individuals who want the feature request can do the work themselves. Have little experience with npm. First encounter was when trying to test jQuery promise implementation re Promises/A+ tests. Then a user decided to convert POC code that had written to workaround a W3C Web Speech API feature request that was not going to get done unless did it for self. If npm do not implement the feature after spec./testing don't host there

Comment: As I have already explained to you, it's a closed source system. Read the **note** [here](https://github.com/npm/download-counts). They are no longer using that repo, and their current system to my knowledge is closed source. You can't extend a system you can't see. I shall not discuss this further. **Note that wasn't the reason why your answer was removed.**

Comment: @BugHunterUK The answer was deleted because of user flags, and disagreement as to the answer actually answering the question. Which is ok. From perspective here the answer does affirmatively answer the question. That is not going to change. If npm refuses to implement the feature the question is moot. Host your own code and create your own service. Which leads back to the points raised in the answer.

Comment: @guest271314 your answer was removed for the reasons Cody stated above.

Comment: @BugHunterUK Yes. And have stated, disagree with those cited reasons. That is not going to change. The question was off-topic. Decided to post an answer as have experience _asking_ for feature requests, from WHATWG HTML Standard, to W3C Web Speech API specification, to Firefox and Chromium/Chrome browsers, et al. Wrote the code for self, else, would not have been done, just one example [SpeechSynthesisSSMLParser](https://github.com/guest271314/SpeechSynthesisSSMLParser)

Comment: @BugHunterUK [How to extract SSML parsing code of espeak to implement SSML parsing at SpeechSynthesisUtterance?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/362911/how-to-extract-ssml-parsing-code-of-espeak-to-implement-ssml-parsing-at-speechsy); [SSML parsing implementation at browsers](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-voice/2017OctDec/0000.html); [How is a complete SSML document expected to be parsed when set once at .text property of SpeechSynthesisUtterance instance? #10](https://github.com/w3c/speech-api/issues/10)

Comment: Question was off-topic, but you answered knowing it was? I mean.... Knowing how our site is, I think what ended up happening was fairly easy to guess....

Comment: @Patrice Was trying to help the users who were making the feature request. The same time invested in _asking_ someone else to do the work that needed to be done could be used to do the work themselves.

Comment: @guest271314 I don't disagree about that. All I'm saying is that, knowing how the site is, how the rules around off-topic stuff are, and all of that... I think what happened with your answer to an off-topic question is hardly surprising. It seems to me like WAI.

Comment: @Patrice Well, "the rules" are frequently ignored at SE sites, by moderator/management/user. The question had not been closed at that point. Decided to share _experiences_ with the users who were interested in the feature request. Trying to help is not guaranteed to be viewed as such. What is "WAI"?

Comment: @guest271314 "Working as Intended". And by the way "the rules are often disregarded", while true, doesn't mean you should be surprised that your answer is deleted when you disregard them. I don't deny it was useful (to that user). I don't deny it was in an attempt to help. I just reiterate that, knowing our rules, our site, and knowing that people usually frown on answering off-topic questions, you took a risk in doing so here. The end result isn't surprising.

Comment: @Patrice Did not state was surprised. Am not surprised by anything. Expect that most SE user/moderator will not gather this users' contributions, for various reasons. The answer directly provided solution to the question nonetheless. Whether the OP and interested users consider the contribution helpful or not is their prerogative.

Comment: @guest271314 Lol.... I'll stop replying, cause this is pointless. You're not surprised it got removed cause you knowingly answered an off-topic question. But then you open this meta question to get it undeleted? knowing it's against the rules? You're either pushing knowingly for something against our rules, or you're just doing this to rant.... in either way, I think I have better use of my time. And you probably do to :). Have a good one!

Comment: @Patrice Why was the question not closed first?

Comment: @guest271314 "I'll stop replying". Please respect that :). Cheers!

Comment: Dude anybody who has been here long enough has been just as frustrated as you are for one reason or another. The time you're wasting on this could be invested in answering some questions and helping people ... if that's your intent. This place is a bit different to Reddit, IRC, Discord etc. I've been burned many times my friend.

Comment: Thanks for your work @Cody Gray ♦

Answer (score 23):

I flagged for removal because the answer you provided was not a solution, or an answer, to the OP's problem. You should check out the guides on how to provide a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/answering

Comment: Yes, the answer does answer the question. Do the work now, then when the question is asked as to how the feature should work you will already have the answers, and will have tested edge cases. Not sure why that is a difficult concept to grasp. How do you expect the feature to work? What are the edge cases? You can answer those questions yourself by doing the work right now. Otherwise you are simply asking npm or someone else to do the work for you. What is stopping you from writing the specification and performing the testing right now?

Comment: @guest271314: Maybe I don't get it. But how is "Write a specification and some tests" an answer to " How can I query the download numbers for a specific version on NPM"?

Comment: @BDL 1) Idea 2) Clear parameters of idea (specification) 3) Testing (POCs, esp. edge cases). The request is simply a URL that is parsed. Otherwise, the questions will be "How should the feature work"? (1) "What are the edge cases" (2) "What occurs when X, Y and Z happens?" (3), which will need to be answered in due course anyway. Implementation of feature requests do not go from request to implementation without 1, 2 and 3. Each of 1, 2, and 3 can be done, right now, by the individuals interested in the feature request. When asked 1, 2, 3 by maintainers, the questions will have been addressed.